# Simple Function Integration

Tags: measure-theory

Defintion: Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a positive measure space, and let $\varphi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be non negative simple function with a canonical representation:

$$\varphi=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kI_{E_k}$$

Then:

$$\int_{X}\varphi d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\mu(E_k)$$

Theorem: Let assume $\varphi=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jI_{E_j}\geq 0$ is a simple function not in canonical representation such the $E_j$ disjoint then:

$$\int_{X}\varphi d\mu=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j\mu(E_j)$$

1. What is the definition of a canonical representation? is it writing $\varphi=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kI_{E_k}$ as disjoint $E_k$
2. What is the theorem for?

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi$ is a simple function then its range $R$ is finite.

If the cardinality of $R$ is $n$ and $R=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ then we can write: $$\sum_{k=1}^na_k1_{E_k}$$ where $E_k=\phi^{-1}(\{a_k\})$ for $k=1,\dots,n$.

That can be labeled as "canonical representation of $\phi$".

Observe that in that case $\{E_1,\dots,E_n\}$ is a partition of $\mathbb R$ (actually the coarsest partition that can be used in this context).

If $\phi$ is measurable and nonnegative then *using* this representation we *define* the integral of $\phi$ by:$$\int\phi\;d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\mu(E_k)$$

*Using this* we expand the definition of integral to integrable functions and prove theorems like:

- $\int cf\;d\mu=c\int f\;d\mu$
- $\int f+g\;d\mu=\int f\;d\mu+\int g\;d\mu$

Based on these theorems we observe that in general statements like:$$\int\sum_{k=1}^na_k1_{E_k}=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\mu(E_k)$$are *also valid* if the measurable sets $E_k$ are *not* necessarily disjoint.

Comment: We first define the intergal on a canonical representation of a simple function, Then the theorem help us integrate simple function that are not in canonical representation?

Comment: Yes. The definition of integration starts with indicator functions. Then is expanded to nonnegative simple functions where it uses the canonical representation. Then is expanded to nonnegative measurable functions. Then is expanded to measurable function that are integrable. If that's done then the theorems I mention can be proved in the general and after that they can be applied on simple function eventually not in canonical representation.

Comment: The $a_k$'s can have the same values?

Comment: Not in the canonical representation. There they are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

1. The canonical representation $\varphi=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kI_{E_k}$ means: the sets $E_j$ are pairwise disjoint and $X= \bigcup_{j=1}^nE_j.$
2. The theorem says that the integral $\int_{X}\varphi d\mu$ is independent of the representation of $ \varphi.$

Comment: 1. if $\varphi$ is defined as $1$ for $(-\infty,0)$ and $2$ for $[0,\infty)$ then the canonical representation is $1\cdot I_{(-\infty,0)}+2\cdot  I_{[0,\infty)}$? a non canonical representation will be $1\cdot I_{(-\infty,-10)}+1\cdot I_{[-10,0)}+2\cdot  I_{[0\infty)}$?

Answer (score 0):

For the integration of simple functions, the sum of discrete point functions considering 2D Euclidean space may be visualized.

Comment: ...... a very strange "answer" to the question .....